# Constructor dependency resolution for multiple ctors having same number of paramters

Tags: ninject

I have 2 constructors defined like so:

```
public interface IMyService<T1,T2>{}
public class MyService1 : IMyService<SomeTypeA,SomeTypeB>
{
    public MyService2(string serviceAUri,IServiceB svc){}
    public MyService2(IServiceA svc,IServiceB svc){}

}
public class MyService2 : IMyService<SomeTypeC,SomeTypeD>
{
    public MyService2(string serviceAUri,IServiceB svc){}
    public MyService2(IServiceA svc,IServiceB svc){}
```

<del>public MyService2(IServiceC svc,IServiceD svc){}</del> 
    }

I am registering multiple service implementations of the IMyService on different values of T1 and T2 so the registration mechanism would have to be generic across implementations of the interface.

How can I specify which constructor to invoke without using [Inject] attributes? Is there some convention that I can specify in the "Bind" that would guide Ninject to pick the constructor with the "url" parameter over the others?

Comment: Take a step back and take a look why you are having multiple constructors? This is a design smell to say the least? Your `MyService2` has multiple definitions of what dependencies are required. This probably means that this class has multiple responsibilities and should be split up into multiple classes.

Comment: Single Responsibility Principle is on the run!! Please keep your doors and windows locked, if you see SRP, do not approach but call a member of the SRP Enforcement!

Comment: The 2nd ctor in MyService2 was a contrived example and I've striked it out.In the above example the class can either take an existing instance of IServiceA or an URL that it can use to construct an instance of IServiceA, IServiceB could be any additional helper service (say logging etc.), in that it is doing one thing just taking in dependencies or using a ctor overload to construct one if needed. Is it better to do the above or just have one ctor which takes in IServiceA and IServiceB and not provide the overload at all?

Comment: What version of Ninject do you use?

Comment: mipe34:Ninject.MVC3 3.0.0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend not to have multiple constructors. The only situation I can think of where this is relevant is if you are not the owner of the class. E.g. injecting a .NET library class somewhere. In that rare case you can define the constructor using the `ToConstructor` overload:

```
int someConstantValue = 1;
Func<int> someOtherValue = () => Random(10);
Bind<IFoo>.ToConstructor(c => new Foo(c.Inject<IBar>(), someConstantValue, someOtherValue, c.Inject<IBaz>());
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up designing a "wrapper" interface and having 2 implementations. One which is constructed using the "serviceAUri" and the other which is a wrapper around an existing instance of IServiceA. With this change MyService1 has a single ctor which takes in a "IServiceAWrapper" instead of having the overload which takes the serviceURL.